# Do any languages have a nominal suffix meaning 'former' or 'ex-'?

Tags: possession, descriptive-linguistics

I have some examples like this from an undated manuscript about an unnamed language and I'm trying to extrapolate some observations about the nominal systems.

> *zumbru* – hat – 'hat'
>   *zumbru-g* – hat-1poss – 'my hat'
>   *zumbru-:-g* – hat-FORMER-1poss – 'my former hat' (but not anymore my hat!)

I'm not sure how to gloss the *-:-* suffix here. It means ‘former’ but only seems to be used in possessive constructions.

Do you know any other languages that have such a suffix and if so, how is it glossed?

Comment: Is this a real language?

Comment: Yes, it's a real language. Is there a technical name for a nominal suffix meaning like "ex-" - would it be inflectional or derivational?

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: As I said, I don't know. I just have the data. I guess it's an interlanguage,  Amazonian (Carib?) + Spanish. Any idea of how to gloss a suffix like "former"?

Comment: I do not really think we can comment on unsourced data in an unidentified language.

Comment: So there's no precedent for a morpheme meaning "Former" or "ex" in any languages with which you are familiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Guarani, the derivational suffix -kue means former, ex-. It's also used in Jopara, the mix of Guarani and Spanish.